# What is the molecular weight of Tris(ethylenediamine)cobalt(III) iodide pentahydrate?

Tags: concentration

What is the molecular weight of 
Tris(ethylenediamine)cobalt(III) iodide pentahydrate ?

The chem formula is: (Co(en)3(I)3*5(H2O)

According to my calculation, it is: 928.77 g/mol. 
But I am uncertain as to whether this is correct or not.

---

Edit: A simple overview for the correct calculation for anyone who might stumble upon this question in the future:

[Co = 58.933 g/mol]
+ [(en)*3 = 180.30 g/mol]
+ [I*3 = 380.712 g/mol]
+ [H * 10 = 10.08 g/mol]
+ [O * 5 = 80 g/mol]

---

= approximately 710.03 g/mol

Comment: Seriously, if you don't trust your own calculations, get a molecular weight calculator. [Here is one by Matthew Monroe](https://omics.pnl.gov/software/molecular-weight-calculator) that is quite trustworthy and mature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked, here is the ChemDraw figure with analysis window for Tris(ethylenediamine)cobalt(III) iodide only. To have a pentahydrate, you may add $\pu{18.02 g/mol} \times 5 = 90.1$ to the $619.95$, which gives a total of $\pu{710.05 g/mol}$ for the formula weight. Thus, your answer, $\pu{928.78 g/mol}$, is way beyond this value.

[image: Cobalt(III)]

Comment: Thank you for showing me the correct answer with the clear explanation! @Mathew Mahindaratne